# Python select from SQL table by date

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I try to download data from a table on pgAdmin within a given time range. i have the code below but it doesn't work and i cannot figure out why.
'''

```
ts, te=df['Timestamp'].min(), df['Timestamp'].max()

connection=psycopg2.connect('dbname=dbname user=user '
                        'password=password host=IP')
print(r'Connection to database is successful')
crsr=connection.cursor()
query="""SELECT * 
FROM public.scanning_lidar_ver2
ORDER BY timestamp ASC, scan_id ASC, range ASC
WHERE timestamp >= %(date_start)s AND timestamp <= %(date_end)s
"""
crsr.execute(query,
             {'date_start' : ts,
              'date_end':te})
df1= pd.DataFrame(crsr.fetchall())
```

''
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the error message you received?

Comment: SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "WHERE"

Comment: order by comes after where: `... WHERE timestamp >= %(date_start)s AND timestamp <= %(date_end)s ORDER BY timestamp ASC, scan_id ASC, range ASC`

Answer (score 1):

Of Note, the `ORDER BY` clause always comes at the **END** of a `SELECT` statement. You simply have to swap `ORDER BY` and `WHERE` causes in your `query`.

If your column names are correct, I would guess the rest of your query looks bug-free! Good luck!

I would suspect you cannot use`df1= pd.DataFrame(crsr.fetchall())`.
Try:

```
exq=crsr.execute(query,
             {'date_start' : ts,
              'date_end':te})
df1=pd.DataFrame(exq.fetchall())
```

Comment: thanks, no error message anymore but it returns an empty dataframe. Table and column names double checked and they are correct

Comment: See the edited answer, though I am not sure it works. Or as the other answer says, try sqlalchemy!

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you use pandas with sqlalchemy.
it easily help use pandas with sql

try this

```
pd.read_sql(query_str, connection)
```